# Restoring Correct Version of Syncfusion Nuget Package

Tags: .net, wpf, nuget, maui, syncfusion

I use Syncfusion components in my WPF and MAUI apps. I have asked this on the Syncfusion forums but no responses.

When I build my solution, I always get the warning:

```
[NU1701] Package 'Syncfusion.Shared.WPF 21.1.37' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Syncfusion state that their components are .NET7 compatible but I'm unsure why Nuget is pulling the .NET Framework version rather than the .NET Core version.

Is there any way of forcing the .NET Core version of these libraries?

Comment: Based on the page https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Shared.WPF it is .NET6-windows compatible.

Comment: Same issue. I switch my assembly to .NET 6 (<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework> in csproj file) and I get exactly the same warning, even after refreshing the Nuget cache.

Comment: Got it - it can't just be .net6. It has to be .net6.0-windows7.0.